# Unformatted date time in response from step function execution history

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am calling below method to get the execution's history of a step function as mentioned in AWS Docs .

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_GetExecutionHistory.html

when i call same method passing the ARN i get response but with date time is not in correct format

```
client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
response = client.get_execution_history(
executionArn=arn,
reverseOrder=True
)
```

I get the response like below

Part of response

```
{
   "events":[
      {
         "timestamp":datetime.datetime(2022,
         5,
         13,
         4,
         50,
         13,
         947000,
         "tzinfo=tzlocal())",
         "type":"ExecutionSucceeded",
         "id":49,
         "previousEventId":48,
         "executionSucceededEventDetails":{
```

and that's why when we try to import to step function it throws error

Can some one help how we can get valid json specially time stamp part on correct format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_execution_history](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.get_execution_history) returns event timestamps as Python `datetime`s.  Convert them to ISO strings with the `isoformat` method:

```py
def with_iso_ts(e):
  ts = {"timestamp": e["timestamp"].isoformat()}
  e.update(ts)
  return e

events = [with_iso_ts(e) for e in response["events"]]

json_encoded = json.dumps(events)
```

Returns the expected string timestamp output:

```py
[{'timestamp': '2022-04-22T16:13:49.241000+02:00',
  'type': 'ExecutionSucceeded',
  'id': 14,
  'previousEventId': 13,
```

Comment: When i do that it says json is not valid

Comment: @AtharvThakur  `events` is a Python list.  If you need to encode it as a JSON string, use `json.dumps(events)`.

Comment: The only issue i have when import to new step function its not recognizing the execution history .

Comment: @AtharvThakur we have solved the JSON problem.  There may be other issues with your code, but it's hard to say without any context.  Sounds like a new question.